# What happens when we replace "</body>" by " &lt;!--</body>--&gt; &lt;/body&gt; " in blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

Many themes in Blogger, I see `</body>` is replaced by `&lt;!-- </body> --&gt; &lt;/body&gt;` Why it is done??
what changes happen after doing it?

Comment: That code remove Blogger CSS widget bundle ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911018/how-to-remove-blogger-css-widget-bundle)).

Comment: btw.: in the new version of the Blogger-Templates, this hack is not needed, since you can use the attribute `b:css='false'` of the `html`tag, to prevent the default css from loading.

Comment: what is benefit of removing Blogger CSS Widget??

Answer (score 1):

" **`&lt;`** " stands for the **less-than** sign: " **<** "
" **`&gt;`** " stands for the **greater-than** sign: " **>** "
" **`&le;`** " stands for the **less-than** or **equals** sign: " **≤** "
" **`&ge;`** " stands for the **greater-than** or **equals** sign: " **≥** "

**Blogger**
Change

With This Code

```
&Lt;!–</Body>
–&Gt; &Lt;/Body&Gt;
```

Comment: To provide some foundation: This "stands for" concept is sometimes called a control character - basically these characters cannot be typed directly into HTML (the language of your web browser), because HTML uses the less than and greater than symbols to indicate the start of code blocks.