# Why there's an unwanted css & js file on my blog?

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I want to create a blogspot theme from scratch. I have finished creating the basic structure of the theme.

Then I open my [blog](https://varkob.blogspot.com). I see in [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#access) there are CSS and Javascript files that I do not know where it comes from.

My question is, where did the file come from? can I delete from my blog?

[image]

Comment: The government spies.... shhhhh. :| Check your browser plugins, they can do that type of page injection.

Comment: I check cross browser and same issues

Comment: The js file location : https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3538524853-widgets.js and the css location 
https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3213516723-css_bundle_v2.css

Comment: these are probably just resources added by blogspot.fr, you can see those 2 files place come from their site

Comment: Where are you hosting it from? Is the host doing that?

Comment: This is a standart Blogger CSS & JS files. You can remove them this way (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911018/how-to-remove-blogger-css-widget-bundle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are files included by default on every Blogger blog (based on the default theme that was choosen). To remove them, add the following attributes to the **`<html>`** tag at the start of the template code (present under Theme  Customise) -

```
<html b:css='false' b:js='false' ...
```

***b:css='false'*** - Removes the default CSS included by Blogger in the template

***b:js='false'*** - Removes the default JS included by Blogger in the template

Comment: Best answer between answer on other questions!! thanks

Comment: Can you explain, for what blogger include the both files?

Comment: The JS file contains logic for the functioning of majority of the widgets (Contact Form, Archive, etc). The CSS files contain styling for particular widgets as well the theme chosen via the dashboard. For custom built theme's the default CSS isn't of any use but removing the default JS file can interfere with functioning of lots of widgets that Blogger provides

Comment: Will this `b:js='false' ` cause the `data:post.labels` not to work? My post has labels, but `data:post.labels` is empty.