# How to fix the widget script on blogger permanently

Tags: javascript, widget, blogger

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/4286713806-widgets.js"></script>
```

The code is above `</body>`, and is not visible in the "edit html" menu on blogger. I can't delete it. Can I delete the code permanently?

Comment: can you please add any examples?

Comment: Refer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911018/how-to-remove-blogger-css-widget-bundle/48957618

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Blogger CSS widget bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911018/how-to-remove-blogger-css-widget-bundle)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Add `b:js='false'` attribute to your `html` tag.

```
<html b:js='false'> ... </html>
```